# Trying to setup a docker autodeploy to my server. But nginx image is not showing the app

Tags: docker, nginx, vhosts

I create the following docker image

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
RUN CI=true npm test
RUN npm run build
# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/v2.myapp.io
```

Where the nginx.conf is

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name serverip v2.myapp.io www.v2.myapp.io;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And then i execute the following sh

```
docker build -t mycontainer .
docker push mycontainer:latest
ssh root@ip 'docker pull mycontainer:latest' 
ssh root@ip 'docker stop mycontainer'
ssh root@ip 'docker rm mycontainer'
ssh root@ip 'sudo docker run -p 8080:80 -it -d --name mycontainer  mycontainer'
```

Well it works fine, but the address v2.myapp.io points to a blank nginx page, so i guess i have some sort of missconfiguration. But im not sure what else can be happening

Can someone help with this issue?

I remember that when I used to do all this manually, I had a sites-enabled, and a sites-available folder, i have tried creating them and puting the nginx.conf file in but i had no luck

What is failing there?

Comment: Can you hit the page from within the container? Can you hit the page from outside the container, but logged onto `ip`?

Comment: @xdhmoore I can hit the container launched locally, in localhost , port 80:80. but i cant hit it in the remote machine where i have to run the container in 8080 because pprt 80 is already occupied

Comment: Ive just found out that its running on port 8080